# Асинхронный вызов методов в Java посредством ForkJoinPool

Tags: java

Хочу разобраться в тонкостях фреймворка Fork/Join. Увидел два Java-приложения, содержащих некие классы, выполняющие примерно одно и то же, однако есть различия по коду.

Фрагмент кода из первого приложения:

```
RecursiveTask<HashMap<String, Menu>> task = new RecursiveTask<HashMap<String, Menu>>() {
@Override
protected HashMap<String, Menu> compute() {
    List<LoadMenuTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Module module : modules) {
        if (module.getIsActive()) {
            LoadMenuTask loadMenuTask = new LoadMenuTask(module, locale);
            tasks.add(loadMenuTask);
            loadMenuTask.fork();
        }
    }

     …

    for (LoadMenuTask task : tasks) {
        Menu menu = task.join();

     …
    }
    …
}
```

};

Фрагмент кода из второго приложения:

```
RecursiveTask<HashMap<String, Menu>> task = new RecursiveTask<HashMap<String, Menu>>() {
@Override
protected HashMap<String, Menu> compute() {
    List<MenuTask> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Module module : modules) {
        if (module.getIsActive()) {
            MenuTask menuTask = new MenuTask(module, locale);
            tasks.add(menuTask);
        }
    }

     …

     for (MenuTask task : tasks) {
        forkJoinPool.execute(task);
     }

for (MenuTask task : tasks) {
Menu menu = task.join();
…
}
    ...
}
};
```

Сразу уточняю: оба кода рабочие. Видно, что в обоих случаях происходит одно и то же: в цикле формируется некое задание и запускается в асинхронном режиме. Однако если в первом случае для этого используется метод **fork()** самого RecursiveTask, то во втором запуск осуществляется посредством метода **execute()** класса ForkJoinPool. Хотелось бы понять разницу между этими двумя подходами, и есть ли она вообще. Возможно, какой-то из них является более предпочтительным по сравнению с другим. В общем, хочется более глубокого понимания темы. Буду благодарен за любые ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут просто разные пулы задействованы. В первом случае задействован тот который создает jvm. А второй это ваш кастомный(который можно переиспользовать на ваш манер). Второй подход лучше. Ибо вы, так сказать, сами выделяете этот пул и можете им управлять не опасаясь что произойдет что либо плохое. Выполняя в созданном jvm пуле, вы нагрузите все потоки если их будет создано чрезмерно много, и создадите много других непрятностей которые также могут быть.